# Problems installing pyspatialite on OSX using pip

Tags: python, macos

I am not experienced at installing python modules and I am not sure exactly what the errors here are telling me:

```
russells-mini:~ rful011$ pip install pyspatialite
 Downloading/unpacking pyspatialite
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyspatialite (from versions: 2.6.2-spatialite.2.3.1, 2.6.2-spatialite.2.4.0-4, 3.0.1-alpha-0)
```

Looking at the install logs it finds the 3 versions and then says "ignoring'.

Mac OS 10.9.4 with 2.7.I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a pre-release version. Try:

```
pip install --pre pyspatialite
```

Comment: yes, that got the install running but it tried to install an Alpha which failed.  I then tried to install the  2.6.2-spatialite.2.4.0-4 and that build fine.  Was the message actually telling me that I needed to choose which version?